# Quelle expression d’un registre plus courant pourrait remplacer « Dit le gars qui… »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

J’entends souvent cette tournure à l’oral, elle est employée quand on veut répliquer à une critique, à un commentaire.

Exemple:

Une personne dit à une autre personne:

- Tu as de mauvaises habitudes alimentaires, tu devrais manger mieux.
  La réplique:
- Dit celui qui mange du fast-food tous les jours…

Comment: C'est l'hôpital qui se moque de la charité.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Je ne trouve pas la tournure particulièrement soutenue, mais c'est vrai qu'elle est peu courante à l'oral et n'est peut-être pas familière chez les gens qui ne lisent jamais de littérature.

Déjà, pour que les choses soient claires, la formulation grammaticale est parfaitement ordinaire. Après un discours rapporté, on inverse le verbe qui décrit le discours avec le sujet. Ce qui est un peu inhabituel ici, c'est que le discours est rapporté au sein du dialogue lui-même.

> « Bonjour, » dit-il en entrant.

> « Tu devrais manger mieux, » dit mon ami d'un ton sentencieux.

> « Tu devrais manger mieux, », dit mon ami qui pourtant mange du fast-food tous les jours.

> — Tu devrais manger mieux.
> — « Tu devrais manger mieux, », dis-tu, alors que tu manges du fast-food tous les jours.

On peut voir la réponse comme une ellipse du discours rapporté :

> — Tu devrais manger mieux.
> — [« Tu devrais manger mieux, »], dit celui qui mange du fast-food tous les jours.

Il y a évidemment d'autres manières d'exprimer la même idée. Par exemple :

> — Tu devrais manger mieux.
> — Drôle de recommandation venant de quelqu'un qui mange du fast-food tous les jours.

> — Tu devrais manger mieux.
> — Pas très crédible venant de quelqu'un qui mange du fast-food tous les jours.

> — Tu devrais manger mieux.
> — Parlé comme quelqu'un qui ne mange pas du fast-food tous les jours.

> — Tu devrais manger mieux.
> — J'y croirais plus si ça venait de quelqu'un qui ne mange pas du fast-food tous les jours.

Comment: Je le vois comme quand tu as un écriteau et tu vieux rajouter un reste de phrase pour faire dire un truc loufoque, une _récupération_ ? Un moyen de prendre la balle au bond...

Comment: Peu courante ? Je l'entends et l'utilise régulièrement, et pourtant pas dans des cercles particulièrement littéraires...

Comment: Je ne comprends pas non plus la phrase "Parlé comme quelqu'un..."

Comment: @LaurentS. Je pense que c'est surtout utilisé avec un nom (et souvent avec un adjectif comme « vrai ») : « parlé comme un vrai buveur de bière », « parlé comme un pur technicien »... Mais je l'utilise et je l'entends aussi avec « quelqu'un qui … » quand l'idée ne peut pas être exprimée avec un nom.

Answer (score 5):

Pour signaler qu'on cite les propos d'une personne avec distance ou ironie, on peut aussi utiliser *dixit* (généralement invariable, même si c'est à l'origine un verbe latin conjugué à la 3ème personne du singulier. Dans un registre soutenu, on peut trouver *dixeunt* au pluriel). Cela peut aussi s'utiliser juste après les propos eux-mêmes:

> Tu as de mauvaises habitudes alimentaires, tu devrais manger mieux.

> ...dixit celui qui mange du fast-food tous les jours ...

En s'éloignant de la formulation initiale, on peut aussi utiliser les expressions suivantes:

- *c'est l'hôpital qui se moque de la charité* (quand quelqu'un formule un conseil ou une critique qu'il devrait s'appliquer d'abord à lui-même)
- *c'est la paille et la poutre* (d'après une parabole de la Bible: cela pointe l'hypocrisie qui consiste à critiquer un petit défaut d'une autre personne mais  à ignorer ses propres défauts parfois plus graves)

Answer (score 4):

Tu peux remplacer ***le gars*** par ***celui*** :

> **Dit**<sup>1</sup> **celui** qui mange [...]

D'autre part, s'il s'agit du lieu où il mange :

> [...] **au fast-food tous** les jours.

S'il s'agit du type de nourriture :

> [...] **de la junk-food tous** les jours.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>La troisième personne de l'indicatif est bien sûr correcte et idiomatique ici.</sub>

Comment: En fait c’est le « dit » en tête de phrase qui me chicote et la construction qui s’ensuit…

Comment: « Toi qui manges de la junk-food tous les jours, tu te permets de critiquer ma conduite… »

Comment: D'accord, mais de là à accepter la réponse de LPH qui n'a rien compris à ta phrase, il y a un pas...

Comment: Il aurait fallu mieux expliquer ce que tu entends par "un registre plus courant". J'avais compris *moins relâché* à cause de *gars*.

Comment: La phrase en question s’apparente à la variante qu’en a donnée LPH «Tu peux parler, de la junk-food tous les jours. »

Comment: Je pense donc, au vu des solutions de rechange qu’il m’a proposées, qu’il a raison: l’impératif s’impose.

Comment: Non, tu parles mieux français que lui...

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette Mets la phrase au pluriel : « disent les gens qui mangent du fast-food tous les jours ».

Comment:  Tu es en train de me rendre hésitant jlliagre! Pour ne pas dire confus! Apparemment je vais devoir retourner sur les bancs de l’école primaire.

Comment: @Gilles ´SO nous est hostile: La réplique constituerait donc un prolongement, une continuité de la remontrance dite par le critique?

Comment: Oui, c'est exactement ça, et c'est courant en français.

Comment: Ha ha! Et voilà! Encore merci jlliagre. Je t’ai décerné « la meilleure réponse », mais il faut dire que la réponse de LPH avait du sens, peut-être pas en France mais au Québec, si.

Comment: Je ne pense pas que le fait que ce soit au Québec ou pas influe sur quoi que ce soit ici. LPH a proposé des phrases potables, mais son premier paragraphe montre qu'il n'a pas compris la tournure utilisée, même s'il a plus ou moins compris ce que tu souhaitais dire.

Comment: Maintenant, ne te sens pas non plus obligé d'accepter ma réponse. Je ne serais pas du tout contrarié si tu acceptais la réponse de Gilles vu qu'elle développe bien mieux le sujet que ma réponse un peu lapidaire.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette Je viens du Québec et ma réaction à la réponse de LPH est la même que celle des gens d'Europe: il n'a pas compris la tournure. Il a perçu une agressivité incontestable, ce qui l'a entraîné à revoir la ponctuation car elle ne correspondait pas au ton qu'il avait en tête. Il n'a pas perçu que ce genre de réplique est plutôt facétieux qu'hostile.

Answer (score -7):

Cette réplique n'est pas ponctuée normalement ; le mot « dit », qui a ici la forme de l'impératif et s'écrit donc « dis », formule un reproche et il est proféré sur un ton apparenté à celui de l'invective, celui du mépris ; on s'attend donc à des point de suspension ou plus habituellement un point d'exclamation.

- Dis ! Le gars qui mange du fast-food à tous ses repas…

*Variante*

- Dis donc ! Le gars qui mange du fast-food à tous ses repas…

Il n'existe pas de formulation plus courante, mais au lieu de cela de nombreuses formulations alternatives qui sont énoncées avec le même ton méprisant.

La suivante est assez courante.

- Tu peux parler, du fast-food à tous les repas…

*En voilà d'autres*

- Du fast-food à tous les repas et tu veux me donner des leçons ?
- Du fast-food à tous les repas… et tu veux m'apprendre quelque chose ? (*intonation montante pour « Du fast-food à tous les repas » ; évidemment les propositions coordonnées dans l'énonciation précédente et celle-ci sont interchangeables.*)
- Occupe-toi (d'abord) de ce que tu manges, parce qu'à tous tes repas ce n'est que du fast-food.  (*On peut mettre une intonation emphatique sur « tu ».*)
- Avant de parler des autres occupe-toi de ton cas, tu ne manges pas autre chose que du fast-food à tous les repas.
- Quand on mange du fast-food à tous ses repas on (ne) se mêle pas de donner des leçons aux autres !
- Du fast-food à tous les repas et voilà que Monsieur voudrais nous donner des leçons…
- L'Hôpital  qui se moque de la charité… du fast-food tous les jours…

*Il y en a bien d'autres encore…*

Comment: Non, la phrase avec « dis » n'a aucun sens. L'orthographe « dit » est correcte : le sujet est « le gars qui … ». C'est un sujet inversé après un dialogue rapporté au discours direct, très courant à l'écrit, peu courant à l'oral.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' « Dit celui qui mange du fast-food tous les jours » est une réplique et donc « dit » le début d'une phrase ; c'est ce que montre le texte : « … La réplique: Dit celui qui mange du fast-food tous les jours… ». Ça ne peut pas être autre chose.

Comment: Il m'a fallu lire la phrase au moins trois fois pour comprendre: "Dis l'étrangère dont la langue maternelle n'est pas le français. Ouf.

Comment: @Lambie Comme ça, on  dira  que vous savez lire entre les lignes !